# accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath not called on Detail accessory touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a `UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailDisclosureButton` but cannot get it to call `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` when the detail icon is tapped. My parent view inherits from `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and is linked to the delegate and datasource of the table in IB. Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.resultsView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell
    if self.tableItems.count == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No Results Found."
    } else {
        //cell.accessoryView =
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailDisclosureButton
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableItems[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}
```

and my `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {        
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Failure"
    alert.message = "YUP"
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath called")
    alert.show()

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("locationDetailSegue", sender : self)
}
```

The table displays the (i) icon just fine, but when I click it, nothing gets fired. I have a view set up with a segue to push to, but it doesn't even seem to be calling the method as I don't even get an alert box. [image: sample table row]

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for that, a bit fried after looking at this all morning

Comment: Check if you don't have any custom views in the front of the cell. Or if you have any UISwipeGestureRecognizer inside the view.

Comment: no UISwipeGesture anywhere. When you press on the detail button it clearly depresses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it works as specified, since Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellAccessoryType) says:

> DisclosureIndicator
>
> The cell has an accessory control shaped like a chevron. This control indicates that tapping the cell triggers a push action. **The control does not track touches.**

Comment: That's right, but I'm talking about the Detail Indicator, which does track touches. In the example I use DisclosureDetail which has a chevron and a info button and also tracks touches. I only really want the info button, but tried this in response to a SO thread I found.